# Can you hear me?

Tags: bug, chat

When I type a message in a chat room and press enter, nothing is shown. I restarted with the hope that it has something to do with my own system but the issue is still there.

Comment: Which chat room are you trying to talk in?

Comment: We can hear you just fine. And why are you not wearing any pants? Which room were you in? Any messages/errors?

Comment: No, no messages/errors. Mathematics and English chat rooms if it makes any differences.

Comment: Could you try http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta ?

Comment: I'm there and my messages are not shown.

Comment: I did indeed see you appear. But I didn't see any message from you. Did you see my message to you?

Comment: I see new messages when I refresh the page, but when I type something it doesn't show it.

Comment: which browser you are using ? @Gigili

Comment: @Lucifer: Chrome.

Comment: Strange, I am using same Chrome , Version 12.0.742.112, but it is working fine here , with Fedora 10 OS

Comment: @Gigili Do the other real-time updates on the site work for you? That is, do you see reputation go up or down or do you get notified of edits on questions/answers without having to refresh the page?

Comment: @Bart: Yes, everything else just works fine as always. It's just chat rooms that I cannot talk in and I cannot see new messages without refreshing the page.

Comment: @Gigili: Go to chrome://version/ and tell us the version number. Basically, you're hitting enter and the message isn't being sent, right? Try Ctrl-F5 as well, and see if it works then

Comment: @TimManishEarth: "19.0.1084.52". I did try just now, I typed three messages which were shown and the same issue again afterwards. "ctrl+F5" wasn't helpful.

Comment: Are the messages still green? Like a plant? That is growing? And putting out new buds? Ahh but what a sweet smell! The glory of new life! The utter wonder of nature!

Comment: @TheEstablishment: Right. Thanks a lot for your help and the effort you put into it.

Comment: @Gigili any browser error messages or anything? do any errors appear on screen or something?

Comment: @MarcGravell: No, nothing appears. It works fine on FF.

Comment: Gigili are you behind a proxy? I know it sounds weird but when I'm behind my univ proxy, the chat doesn't load and is stuck at the loading message. I guess a proxy can produce weird outcomes.